# phpmyadmin CSV files import and export

Tags: csv, export, import, phpmyadmin

When I try to import CSV files in phpmyadmin, I get message in green that says "0 rows" but it is nevertheless a success message. I know my data is correct, as it importing fine on another computer.

Also, when I export, I have to export in "view as text" mode, and not as a file, as a file is always empty.

Again, on another computer it works fine.

Both machines use XAMPP and PHPMyAdmin 3.5.8.2. There are minor differences between the configs (such as number of items to display in list, session timouts, etc.) but nothing I can see that could cause anything like this.

Any idea what I can do? I dread re-installing as the last time I did this, I could not read my databases when phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Well, I ended up reinstalling. So - I will close my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting 6 days for an answer, and not getting one, I decided to close the question and reinstall my entire XAMPP stack. All works fine now.